# Suddenly kicked out of server, can't reconnect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm running a Minecraft private server for my friends from my desktop (Win10 version 1903; Minecraft JE 1.15.1, no mods). I've also been playing on this server by using the regular JE client and going to Multiplayer and putting in my own public IP as the server address. So far, so good.

A couple days ago I was in the middle of playing and I got kicked out. Now when I try to connect I just get Can't Connect to Server/Connection Timed Out errors as if the server were completely gone. Yet according to the server window, everything is fine, and apparently I just disconnected of my own accord.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- In client, log out of Mojang and back in
- Restart client
- Restart server
- Check for version mismatch (both 1.15.1)
- Restart computer
- Restart router
- Check connectivity to other servers (I can connect to myne.fun OK)
- Verify public IP (hasn't changed according to whatismyip.com)

I'm particularly thrown off by the part where it's not like I couldn't get it working (which could be any number of configuration/firewall issues), but that it *was* working and stopped working right in the middle of a session. How can I get the connection back?

Comment: Oh, you mean "Windows 10, version 1903", meaning "Java edition on Windows 10", not "Windows 10 version", meaning "Bedrock edition". This naming scheme is so confusing…

Comment: Can you try joining from the same computer that it's running on, using "`localhost`" as the IP? That way you could verify that it's not a firewall issue on either computer or the router. Who knows, maybe the router downloaded an update to its firewall that somehow messed things up.